# Scope Jest globals in TypeScript to certain files

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Adding `@types/jest` to my package.json is making TypeScript and VS Code think all .ts files have several additional globals (`test`, `describe`, `expect`, `afterAll`, `afterEach`, `beforeEach`). Is there any way to mark it only apply to .jest.ts files or something?

Alternatively, can you make it a requirement to have to import these functions instead of them being global?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could force the import of globals by setting `importGlobals: false` in the config file: https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/next/configuration#injectglobals-boolean

However, I prefer to have all the test files in one folder, so you can just add a tsconfig.json to it with:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/jest"]
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't want the test files in one folder. I have a monorepo, where it makes much more sense to put test files near the files they are testing. The import globals idea may be what I go with if I can't find something better.